Why does conda throw the error with tk when I try to install literally any package
CondaVerificationError: The package for tk located at /home/greedybad/anaconda3/pkgs/tk-8.6.12-h1ccaba5_0 appears to be corrupted. The path 'include/mysqlStubs.h' specified in the package manifest cannot be found.
This is what popped up when I ran conda install scikit-learn and pressed 'y' in the preceding popup. I'm on Ubuntu 23.10
I just created the conda environment using the command conda create --name learning_env and I gave the command conda install scikit-learn
thanks in advance
